# Is NPOI better than Office Interop in C# for automation using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, npoi

I am using C# and Selenium WebDriver for automating our web application. The test data will be read from Excel sheets(.xlsx). Being new to C#, I want to know if using NPOI is a good option to read/write data from Excel or using Interop in C# is a preferred. I personally prefer NPOI as I feel it is easier to use. This could be because of my exposure to Apache POI when I used Java and Selenium for automation. Kindly help.

Answer (score 6):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

Don't use Office Interop in web environments.

Answer (score 2):

At first, as mentioned already, Interop requires actual Excel application to be installed on server, which is not always a good idea ar may even be not possible at all (i.e. if you are yousing Azure Web Apps). I'm currently working on a project which we have rewritten using Interop, but now are going to migrate to NPOI mainly because of it's speed: some tasks require around 5-8 seconds using Excel Interop, because it actually launches full Excel app and communicates with it via RPC. NPOI works directly with Excel files and today while testing one heave action was performed in just around 300 milliseconds including saving modified workbook to new file.
So if you have to work specifically with old binary .xls files NPOI is good choise. If you are going to work with modern OpenXML files (.xlsx), take a look at https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml

Answer (score 1):

The microsoft solution to office document automation is Open Xml : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx